# labelprefix to newrefcontext replacing prefixnumbers to printbibliography not working

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

After updating `biblatex` of MikTex 2.9 I get the following error message when using:

```
\printbibliography[prenote=conference, keyword=C, prefixnumbers={C}]
```

> Package biblatex Warning: prefixnumbers option to \printbibliography
>   is no longer supported, use 'labelprefix' option to \newrefcontext.

However, when I use instead:

```
%...
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[prenote=conference, keyword=C]
```

I get the following error message (line 17 being the \printbibliography...):

> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 17.

Here is a complete minimal working example with both variants (one is commented out):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, cleardoublepage=plain, openright]{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
  @inproceedings{test-conference,
    author = {Test Author 1},
    title = {Test Title 1},
    booktitle = {Test Booktitle 1},
    year = {2016},
    keywords = {C}
  }
  @inproceedings{test-workshop,
    author = {Test Author 2},
    title = {Test Title 2},
    booktitle = {Test Booktitle 2},
    year = {2016},
    keywords = {W}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=bibtex, bibencoding=ascii, defernumbers=true, maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}

  Conference paper: \cite{test-conference}
  Workshop paper: \cite{test-workshop}.

  \defbibnote{conference}{Conference Papers}
  \defbibnote{workshop}{Workshop Papers}


  % #### Variant 1 ####
  % ## Producing error: Package biblatex Warning: prefixnumbers option to \printbibliography is no longer supported, use 'labelprefix' option to \newrefcontext.
  % ## Generating output with bibliography but without C or W as prefix.
  \printbibliography[prenote=conference, keyword=C, prefixnumbers={C}]
  \printbibliography[prenote=workshop, keyword=W, prefixnumbers={W}]

  % #### Variant 2 ####
  % ## Producing error: LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line ...
  % ## Generating output completely without bibliography.
  % \newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
  % \printbibliography[prenote=conference, keyword=C] 
  % \newrefcontext[labelprefix=W]
  % \printbibliography[prenote=workshop, keyword=W] 

\end{document}
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE: Thanks to Guido's advise, it (almost) works after I changed the backend option to biber as shown below. I now get the bibliographies with the prefixes as desired. However, in the document where I cite the references, I get [0] instead of [C1] or [W1], respectively. Interestingly, there is no error message or warning from pdflatex during compilation.

```
\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber, bibencoding=ascii, defernumbers=true, maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

  Conference paper: \cite{test-conference} should be [C1] but is [0].
  Workshop paper: \cite{test-workshop} should be [W1] but is [0].

  \defbibnote{conference}{Conference Papers}
  \defbibnote{workshop}{Workshop Papers}

  \newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
  \printbibliography[prenote=conference, keyword=C] 
  \newrefcontext[labelprefix=W]
  \printbibliography[prenote=workshop, keyword=W] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's causing this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would it be possible to provide the code of a full example document that shows the problem (an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864))? It will be much easier for us to diagnose your problem if you show us a full document that causes the error and not just a few snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! I just added an MWE that is hopefully helping to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `prefixnumber` is no longer supported, and you have to change to `labelprefix` option of `refcontext`. It seems to me that `refcontext`s are not supported by the `bibtex` backend, so you  have switch to `biber` as backend. When you do, it seems there is a problem with the `ieee` style.

Comment: Thanks Guido! Changing the backend to biber did in fact help! I could not reproduce what you maybe encountered as problems with the ieee style...

However, now the citations in the document do not get the respective labels but only [0], as I have shown in the update in the bottom of my original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber, defernumbers=true, maxnames=10]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{test-conference,
  author    = {Test Author 1},
  title     = {Test Title 1},
  booktitle = {Test Booktitle 1},
  year      = {2016},
  keywords  = {C},
}
@inproceedings{test-workshop,
  author    = {Test Author 2},
  title     = {Test Title 2},
  booktitle = {Test Booktitle 2},
  year      = {2016},
  keywords  = {W},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Conference paper: \cite{test-conference}
Workshop paper: \cite{test-workshop}.

\defbibnote{conference}{Conference Papers}
\defbibnote{workshop}{Workshop Papers}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[prenote=conference, keyword=C] 
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=W]
\printbibliography[prenote=workshop, keyword=W] 
\end{document}
```

produces the desired and expected output

[image: Conference paper: [C1] Workshop paper: [W1].]

But you will have to use Biber instead of BibTeX, because only Biber supports `labelprefix` properly. (Starting with `biblatex` 3.13 a rudimentary version of `labelprefix` is supported even with the BibTeX backend, but there are some differences to the proper/full implementation available with Biber, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/852. In general you can only use all of `biblatex`'s features with Biber, so it is a very good idea to switch to Biber anyway.)

Since this MWE needs to use `defernumbers` it may happen that the citation numbers get stuck at "[0]" or in a different unwanted numbering. In those cases it helps to remove the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and recompile from scratch.

---

In very specific situations you may have to have to make sure that the entries belong to the correct refsection even in the citations. Usually this should not be needed, though.

Then you would use `\assignrefcontextkeyws` to make sure the citations get it right. See §3.7.10 *Reference Contexts* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), especially pp. 94-99.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! That this is only necessary for biblatex-ieee is indeed interesting. At least now I know how to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

This should just work as is. The labels in citations pick up the label in the last bibliography in which the reference was printed, by default. This is almost always what you want and with this MWE, it works fine for me. Perhaps a problem with the ieee style?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
  @inproceedings{test-conference,
    author = {Test Author 1},
    title = {Test Title 1},
    booktitle = {Test Booktitle 1},
    year = {2016},
    keywords = {C}
  }
  @inproceedings{test-workshop,
    author = {Test Author 2},
    title = {Test Title 2},
    booktitle = {Test Booktitle 2},
    year = {2016},
    keywords = {W}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric, bibencoding=ascii, defernumbers=true, maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}

Conference paper: \cite{test-conference}
Workshop paper: \cite{test-workshop}.

\defbibnote{conference}{Conference Papers}
\defbibnote{workshop}{Workshop Papers}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[prenote=conference, keyword=C] 
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=W]
\printbibliography[prenote=workshop, keyword=W] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to run your code but I get an error : "Undefined control sequence [...] \newrefcontext". Am I missing something here ? Could there have been a modification of the biblatex package ?

Comment: What version of biblatex are you using? `\newrefcontext` has been around for a while now.

Comment: I have tried Texlive 2014 and 2016. I have been investigating more on this issue, it seems related to my Linux distribution (Fedora 23/24). Indeed, code compiles just fine under Linux Mint with Texlive 2015 and 2016...

Comment: Why \defbibnote{conference}{Conference Papers}
\defbibnote{workshop}{Workshop Papers} solves the referencing problem??