# Biblatex and beamer : bibliography item

Tags: beamer, biblatex, color

I am using Beamer with biblatex.

When I use the code below, it produces the following slide.

I would like to replace the tiny journal picture by [FC1] for the first category (then [FC2] for the second reference in the first category etc...) and [SC1] for the second category (then [SC2], etc...).  Is it possible?

As pointed out in comment, the solution proposes in [How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124256/how-do-i-get-numbered-entries-in-a-beamer-bibliography) do not work here. If I use

```
  \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}
```

I get [0] in front of each article. If I use

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
```

I get nothing in front of each article. In addition, I would like to have FC or SC for my reference depending of the keyword of each article.

[image]

The code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First category
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=FC, heading=none,keyword=fstcat]
\item Second category
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=SC, heading=none,keyword=sndcat]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The .bib file

```
@article {test1,
AUTHOR = {LastName1, FirstName1},
TITLE = {A long title that says nothing interesting},
JOURNAL = {Big journal},
VOLUME = {1},
YEAR = {1111},
NUMBER = {1},
PAGES = {1--111},
keywords={fstcat}
 }

@article {test2,
AUTHOR = {LastName2, FirstName2},
TITLE = {A long title that says nothing interesting again},
JOURNAL = {Very Big journal},
VOLUME = {1},
YEAR = {1111},
NUMBER = {1},
PAGES = {1--111},
keywords={sndcat}
 }
```

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. That makes it easier for those answering your question and it enables others to find answers more quickly.

Comment: @TeXnician The solution proposes in the possible duplicate do not work here. And in addition, I want some extra information in each category.

Comment: @user37238 Why does it not work (have you tried setting it in a biblatex-style)? Extra information can always be added as you use `biblatex`.

Comment: @TeXnician see my edit.

Comment: With `style=authoryear` you won't get labels like 'FC2', you need to use `style=numeric` or similar. Note also that `prefixnumber` is no longer a valid option to `\printbibliography` the option is now called `labelprefix` and needs to be passed to a refcontext environment.

Comment: @moewe I seems to work. Thank you. I'm going to start another question for the color thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will only get labels in the bibliography if you use a style that provides them.

`style=authoryear` does not provide these sort of labels. You probably want

```
style=numeric
```

You will still need the `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` from [How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124256/35864).

Note that in more recent versions of `biblatex` `prefixnumber` has been renamed to `labelprefix` and can no longer be given as an option to `\printbibliography`. You will need to use a refcontext (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317394/35864)).